# what happens if I initialize a virtual function other than 0? will it create a pure virtual function or what else happens in memory?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have created a definition for virtual function and initialized it with (=1) and when I compiled a project it get complied successfully. And because it get compiled successfully I wanted to know what actually happened. does it create a pure virtual function or anything else got happened.

Comment: get compiled successfully? change your compiler...

Comment: Non-pure virtual functions *must* be defined (implemented). Not doing so will lead to an error (when linking).

Comment: And using an "iniitalizer" other than `0` [should lead to a compiler error](https://godbolt.org/z/75G9rq). Please [edit] your question to show us a [mcve] of the code you claim builds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such thing as initializing a virtual function to a value. The grammar `= 0` is a pure-specifier, not an initializer. It is special grammar that is given special meaning; it designates that the virtual function is a pure-virtual function and must be implemented by any classes inheriting from it.

`= 1` following a `virtual` function declaration has no grammatical meaning in C++ and therefore is ill-formed. If you didn't get a compile error, then your compiler is either buggy or you weren't "initializing" a `virtual` function at all.

Comment: I guess this is bug inside the compiler which I am using. I tried the same code on another compiler and that compiler returned me, my error.

Comment: @rjsingh12123 Which compiler *are* you using? And which version of it? As you can see in the compiler explorer link I provided the Visual Studio C++ compiler also reports an error. In the future, please always include details such as this, and always include a [mcve] (it will increase your chances of getting good answers or comments).